# What was supposed to be the plan in A Quiet Place 2?

Tags: a-quiet-place, a-quiet-place-2

I've watched A Quiet Place 2 yesterday and I was confused around the core plan by Regan. The way the film presented it:

1. There was a working radio station on an island, traced via the radio signal frequency and "Beyond the Sea" hint
2. Regan took her hearing aid and portable radio the island
3. Once there, she was supposed to change the radio broadcast but was interrupted by the monsters

But... what was she supposed to replace the broadcast with? Possible options:

1. A recording of the monsters. Not possible as she didn't have a recording of that sound. They did use the hearing aid to kill of a few of them, but neither Part 1 nor Part 2 showed them actually making a recording.
2. Generic microphone feedback noise. Was that enough to kill the monsters though? Or did they need to use their own feedback for that to work?
3. A set of instructions like "hey, use hearing aids to defeat them!"

Was it ever explicitly stated or implied in the movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reagan planned to do exactly what she did. She intended to take her hearing aid to the radio station, and begin broadcasting the frequency from its feedback across the area. Then anyone with a radio would be able to hit the monsters with the feedback and fight them.

Comment: So it was just generic feedback, not feedback from the monster itself making a sound? Accepting.

Comment: Not necessarily generic feedback. It's the feedback that comes from the hearing aid her father made for her. Broadcasting that sound over the radio creates a weapon for every survivor with their own radio.